# redirect to another url

Tags: servlets, redirect

I'm doing redirection in my servlets but the url is always the same and my post and gat parameters doesn't disappear

```
RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/");
dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

In this exemple the url will not change, but the fetch page will be "/"
And my post and get are not destroyed.

I'm trying to find a real redirection as

```
header("location:/");
```

in PHP.

Comment: What page are you trying to redirect to? (what's the relative URL)

Comment: for exemple an inscription page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sendRedirect()` to do a true redirection instead of internal dispatch.

```
response.sendRedirect("/");
```

- Address bar url reflects the change
- Done through the client browser (using `location:` header)
- New request object is created (previous get/post parameters are destroyed)

Comment: Yes, `response.sendRedirect(request.getRequestURI());` will redirect the client to the same URL but without the GET/POST parameters.